# ARREGLO JSON A ARREGLO DE OBJETOS EN JAVA (ANDROID STUDIO)

Tags: php, json

Actualmente estoy pasando desde PHP a través de un JSON un objeto, compuesto por mensaje, resultado y un objeto de 2 atributos: id y nombre de región.

Función de PHP que realiza el `select` y retorna un objeto a la función que llama:

```
public function getAll(){
    $consulta='SELECT * FROM REGION';
    try {
        $query = $this->conn->prepare($consulta);
        $query->execute();

        $data = $query->fetchObject();
        if($query){
            $region["id_region"] = $data -> ID_REGION;
            $region["nombre_region"] = $data -> NOMBRE_REGION;
            return $region;
        } else {
            return false;
        }

    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        return false;
    }
```

Esta es finalmente el PHP que retorna el JSON hacia el cliente:

```
public function listarRegion(){
    $db = $this -> db;
    $total = $db -> getAll();
    if ($total) {

        $response["result"] = "success";
        $response["message"] = "Se adjunta lista de regiones";
        $response["region"] = $total;
        return json_encode($response);

    } else {

        //return json_encode(array(
        $response["result"] = "failure";
        $response["message"] = "No existe datos";
        return json_encode($response);

    }
}
```

Este código funciona correctamente con un registro de la tabla `REGION` que tiene `id_region` y `nombre_region`, sin embargo necesito que lleguen todas las regiones en un arreglo. ¿Cómo podría hacer eso?

Comment: entonces lo que quieres es en PHP crear un json ?

Comment: Claro!, pero un json que lleve un objeto y dentro del objeto un arreglo de regiones.